# nvim: some mappings in init.vim don't load

Tags: neovim

I have some mappings in nvim's init.vim file that don't work when nvim starts up. When I `source ~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, they then become available.

Specifically, the mapping I most notice being missing is:

```
inoremap <expr><tab> pumvisible() ? "\<c-n>" : "\<tab>"
```

I'm sure that nvim is loading the correct init.vim on startup, because adding a syntax error to that file causes an error when nvim starts.

I'd appreciate any help you could offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `:verbose imap <Tab>` to see which plugin is overriding your map.
2. File a bug against the plugin.

Comment: Thank you. It was another plugin overriding my map.

Comment: @jamessan I am experiencing a similar problem with my `noremap -t :vsp<CR><C-w>w:terminal<CR>` mapping. How would I alter this command and where do I place it to see what is overriding my map?

Comment: @libby When you expect the map to work, but it isn't, run `:verbose nmap -t` to see whether the map exists and, if so, what overrode it.